# Unable to use pip due to Permission Error

Tags: python, windows, pip

At the moment, when I try to do anything with pip or pip3, it always returns this error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\My local user name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfi3qmtn7'
```

I'm not sure what the file that's causing this problem is, but I can't install or uninstall packages with pip, nor can I upgrade pip itself. I have the latest version of Python installed as well as Windows 10, and pip was working just fine earlier.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the pip commands ran through the command prompt?

Comment: Open your cmd/powershell as administrator for any pip installs that _have_ to be global (which really should just be pip itself, and things like `invoke` or the like). For everything else, remember to [create a virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and activate it before running pip installs, so that things install local to your project, and won't require admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, pip is currently being used by another process. Check if you have any pip processes running in the background. If you can't see anything, try using Process Explorer ([Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), [Instructions](https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015880627-How-to-Identify-which-Windows-Process-is-Locking-a-File-or-Folder)).

Alternatively, you could try restarting your computer to see if that helps.